# Problem about solvable groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, solvable-groups

Let G be a group of order 80

a) Show that G has a normal Sylow 5-subgroup or a normal Sylow 2-subgroup
b) Show that G is solvable

Approach: $80=5*2^4$

$Syl_5(G) \equiv  1mod \text{ } 5$ and $Syl_5(G) | 16$, so the only possibilities are 1 and 16

$Syl_2(G) \equiv 1 mod \text{ }2$ and $Syl_2(G)|5$, so the only possibilities are 1 and 5

How do we discard one of the possibilities to imply there exists a normal sylow p subgroup in G?

Answer (score 2):

You only need to prove that the case when we have 5 Sylow-2 subgroups and 16 Sylow-5 subgroups is impossible, as otherwise we can use the fact that if a group has a single subgroup of a given order, it's a normal subgroup.

Now assume what I previously mentioned. Then two different Sylow-5 subgroups must have the identity element as the only shared element. Hence the 16 Sylow-5 subgroups give rise to at least $64$ elements of order $5$.

On the other hand take two Sylow 2-subgroups, $P_1$ and $P_2$. Obviously there is an element in $P_1$, not in $P_2$. Therefore there are 16 elements of order divisible by $2$ (The $15$ elemnts in $P_2$ and the one in $P_1$). Also we must have an element of order $1$, the identity. Therefore there are at least $64+16+1=81$ elements in a group of order $80$. A contradiction.

Comment: Or simpler, perhaps: since there are $\;64\;$ elements of order $\;5\;$ , the remaining $\;16\;$ elements **must be** the group of order $\;2^4=16\;$, which is then unique.

Comment: Hello guys, would you be willing to be my tutor. I have a final. I need help

Comment: @daniel I think it's quite irresponsible from you to ask for such an offer. Anyway I can help you with some questions, like this, but that's all I can do. After all we all have a private life and 6 hours is quite a lot of time.

Comment: Yes, that's true, sorry. Ok let's start with the first claim:  as otherwise we can use the fact that if a group has a single subgroup of a given order, it's a normal subgroup. How is that true?

Comment: @daniel If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then the conjugation by any element of $a \in G$ yields another subgroup of $G$ and more importantly $\mid H\mid = \mid aHa^{-1}\mid $. But as $H$ is the only subgroup of the given order then we must have $H = aHa^{-1}$ for each $a \in G$, implying that $H$ is a normal subgroup in $G$.

Comment: @daniel BTW You can check [this site](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Main_Page). There are lots of basic and even more advanced theorems about groups there and also it has proofs for everything.

Comment: I think that you are stating a corollary from second sylow's theorem. Basically, if there exists just one sylow p subgroup of a group then it's normal in it.

Comment: @daniel This one's a little bit different and more general. This proves that if a group of any order is the only one of that order in $G$ it's normal in $G$. On the other hand Sylow Theorems deal with p-subgroups. Actually the main purpose of the Second Sylow Theorem is to prove that any two Sylow p-subgroups are conjugates of each other.